# paypal-rest-sdk angular 8 universal error module not found after npm

Tags: node.js, angular, paypal, angular-universal, paypal-rest-sdk

i just upgraded from angular 5 to angular 8 universal. this is my api.ts file i imported

```
var paypal = require('paypal-rest-sdk');
```

and npm i but when i build its saying module not found.
and this is the error message.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/paypal-rest-sdk/lib/configure.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../package' in '/Users/salvadormireles/Downloads/angular-universal-crud-master/node_modules/paypal-rest-sdk/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/paypal-rest-sdk/lib/configure.js 4:38-59
 @ ./node_modules/paypal-rest-sdk/lib/paypal-rest-sdk.js
 @ ./node_modules/paypal-rest-sdk/index.js
 @ ./routes/users.ts
 @ ./server.ts
```

Comment: That lib is not maintained anymore. Maybe add a package.js file which export the correct version

Comment: that sucks. i will try it out thanks